# Constraining select coefficients to be the same across equations in a SUR system

Tags: python, linearmodels, seemingly-unrelated-regression

I want to estimate Labor Force Participation Rates for different age groups in a system of seemingly unrelated regressions (SUR), regressing them on **some age group specific variables** and **shared birth-cohort dummies**. This is the typical cohort-based approach (see for example [Grigoli et al (2018)](https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/WP/Issues/2018/05/22/A-Cohort-Based-Analysis-of-Labor-Force-Participation-for-Advanced-Economies-45876).

I manage to estimate the system as a SUR using linearmodels, but I cannot figure out how one would specify **constraints that force the coefficients on the birth-cohort dummies to be equal across all equations** where they appear. Is this at all possible with current libraries?

To make an easily replicable example, lets leave Labor Force Participation Rates in favor of a commonly used dataset: Let's say I wanted the estimated "male" coefficient to be the same across the two equations from the example in the package linearmodels vignette:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from linearmodels.datasets import fringe
from collections import OrderedDict
from linearmodels.system import SUR

data = fringe.load()
formula = OrderedDict()
formula["benefits"] = "hrbens ~ nrthcen + male"
formula["earnings"] = "hrearn ~ married + male"

mod = SUR.from_formula(formula, data)
print(mod.fit(cov_type="unadjusted"))
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
constraints_matrix=pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,1]).transpose()
constraints_values=pd.Series(['benefits_male'])
mod.add_constraints(constraints_matrix,constraints_values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after I got inspired by a friend. This is easily formulated in a linear constraint. The coefficient of benefits_male minus earnings_male needs to equal 0:

```
constraints_matrix=pd.DataFrame([0,1,0,-1]).transpose()
constraints_values=pd.Series([0])
mod.add_constraints(constraints_matrix,constraints_values)
print(mod.fit(cov_type="unadjusted"))
```